# How to integrate visual codes using SiriKit in ios application?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, siri, sirikit

Wants to integrate visual codes with SiriKit using swift language. 
Want to make payments, request payments and communicate contact information using scannable QR code. How to integrate and implement visual code with my application and scan visual codes using siri?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to make and request payments vocally, you can look at [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit) and its use of intent domains.

If you're wanting to do it with your camera, such as with QR codes, you will want Apple's [Vision](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) framework. You'll find parts of the documentation specifically for barcode detection.